# Get Json schema of a Type of pydantic model

Tags: python, python-3.x, jsonschema, python-typing, pydantic

I am using pydantic in my project and am using its jsonSchema functions.

I have defined some models using `class MyModel(BaseModel)` and can get the schema of the model using `MyModel.schema()`.

How can I obtain the json schema when the model is used together with `typing.Type`? For example the following:

- `typing.List[MyModel]`
- `typing.Optional[MyModel]`
- `typing.Union[MyModel1, MyModel2]`

Example of what I would like to obtain:

```
MyModelList = typing.List[MyModel]
MyModelListSchema = get_schema(MyModelList)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is now doable using pydantic and `__root__` attribute.

```
class MyModelList(BaseModel):
    __root__: typing.List[MyModel]

MyModelListSchema = MyModelList.schema()
```